# What is the right programing model for global chat app?

Tags: c#, network-programming

I am trying to build a chat app in c# that would work in the wan network. 
There are 2 side in the app. Server side and client side. 
In my thoughts i think that every message from client to client need to be passed to the server and the server will forward it to the right des client. The communications between the clients wont be directelly. 
Is this the right model?
If yes, does the server need to have one socket that will listen to all clients? (Because every client sends his message to the same port at server).
Will the sever can handle management of million of messages on same port?

Comment: Lots of ways to do this.  You should look into non-blocking IO solutions like node.js and vert.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it is really up to what you want to accomplish, each choice has it's own pros and cons.
For example:

Using a centralized server can track messages , which users are online etc... but you will have to manage the ports for each connection (see explanation at the end of the answer for details).

Using  a P2P model, you will not have the bottle neck and management required by the centralized server, but again it might be more of a hassle to manage a non centralized system (depends what exactly you want to accomplish).

If you are going to the centralized design, Typically You would have a server with a port that will listen for requests.
once a user wants to connect, the server will start a new thread for the client, and will assign a port for him (the thread will be typically from a thread pool and the port from a specific port range).
this will allow users to speak to the server in a non-blocking manner, and by that allow for multiple users to use the service simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, my direction is to have centralized server. maybe to store a port at server side that will listen to protocol messsages like connect req etc.. And the text messages will be send directly between the clients? Is it ok to let the client side know the public ip of the client he is talking with? You meant to give every client a uniqe port at server side?

Comment: @AviThalker Yes, I meant give a unique port from a pool for each client. About letting each client know about the IP of the client, It is really up to you. For example Skype uses P2P, meaning the clients are aware of others clients IP

Comment: thank you very much! i think i will try to make centralized server with p2p between clients so text/voice messages will directly transferred between clients and protocol messages will be sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at SignalR and the chat system implemented using SignalR, Jabbr:

http://signalr.net/

http://about.jabbr.net/

Comment: SignalR as i read is for web app right? The chat that i am building isnt a web app.

Comment: Well, yes and no ;-) You could use it self-hosted in an console app for instance. And as I see in your other comment, you plan to use a central server, then a web server or a self-hosted application would be a good solution.

Comment: thank you' i will consider that way (: